# Falling back/relapse how come?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Is anything (a term perhaps) in psychology which explains the quick backsliding or reverting into old, learned and familiar habits, ways, behaviour (traits), relapse-type situations?

How come we we're usually lose our grip of good and new habits so easily: (say exercising, eating healthy, consistent studying etc, keep our emotions under control et).

Comment: The term is simply "relapse"; your second question is separate. Maybe you could make that your question? It's a bit broad but can probably be answered.